# IRC for Creative Writers

Tags: community

Are there any 'active' irc channels designed for writers? I say active, because I've found a couple channels, bit they were all empty.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few floating around that are at least semi-active and usually have a few people in them. I'll list two that I've found helpful:

- [#allnightwriters on snoonet](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.snoonet.org/allnightwriters) stems from the subreddit with the same name.
- [#shutupandwrite on snoonet](https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.snoonet.org/shutupandwrite) is a personal favorite.

There are many others that are more genre-specific, you just have to search a bit.